# Nginx authentication: Only allow traffic through iframes on same server

Tags: ssl, authentication, nginx, reverse-proxy, iframe

I have a large amount of Nginx reverse proxy entries which are all for different web services running on a server. In an attempt to combine these services, which all use different methods of authentication, into a single point of entry; I want to access them through iframes on one existing service which also happens to be a reverse proxy on the same server. This main service already uses Oauth for authentication so I'd like to to secure everything else behind it.

Basically my question is; to provide a single method of authentication for all of these services, how can I setup the reverse proxies to only be accessible through iframes on the same site? I have tried setting the location block for each reverse proxy to only allow the local IP of the server but this gives a 403 error; presumably because the access IP is an external one rather than the server's internal IP?

It is also worth mentioning that this server will only be accessed through an external hostname using TLS/SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get around this by using [Vouch](https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy) and the Nginx auth-request module to add top-level authentication to the entire server. This means I can login with my google account and Oauth 2.0 and remove the individual authentication methods for each web service.